# Gottingen beamer theme without shading

Tags: beamer

I want Gottingen theme to be without shading on the sidebar.

( with shading: http://mcclinews.free.fr/latex/beamergalerie/maxi/goettingen1.png )

```
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{sidebartab}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}[][]
\makeatother
```

I think that it may be related to the above line. How to remove shading?

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). That makes it a lot easier for people to help and increases your chances of getting useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical shading is defined in `beamerthemeGoettingen.sty`:

```
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}[vertical shading]
         [top=structure.fg!25,bottom=structure.fg!10]
```

If you want no shading, include this command in you main document and apply the same color to `top` and `bottom` parameters.

You must use include the command inside `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}[vertical shading]%
          [top=structure.fg!25,bottom=structure.fg!25]
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]